# Ensure that a object is only in one list

Tags: list, reference, reference-counting

I am stuck with a pretty basic question.

I need to ensure that a object is only in one list. 
e.g. i have two lists (pseudo code):

```
Object person = new Object();
List waitingForCoffe = new List();
List waitingForTee = new List();
```

How can i ensure that person is either in:

1. No List
2. List waitingForCoffe or
3. List waitingForTee

But not in booth lists at the same time.
Do i need to ensure that in my code or is there already something existing?
Design Pattern?

Comment: Check that the intersection of the two lists is empty.

Comment: which programming language are you using here ? you can check the intersection of the both lists, if it is empty means he is either in one of the lists or in neither.

Comment: this has nothing to do with your implementation, but I would create a Person object with some field for storing state waiting for coffee/waiting for tee. Then I would override hashcode / equals method, putting those object in a Set :)

Comment: @gipinani I was also thinking about having a field in person, where i could save the information whether it is in "waitingForCoffe" or in "waitingForTee". So i could use this information to remove the object from one list before adding it to the other. But it seems like a hack to me and I though there must be a design pattern for such cases. Because i have more than just two list (with many persons) i am afraid that a intersection could give me performance problems.

Comment: You can also use List contains() method. Apache CollectionUtils may have something more about what you need. I don't know if a design pattern could represent what you need, but you can hide all your logic inside a class that handle internally your lists / collection and with some public method return who is where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could let the "Person" handle the list assignment:

```
public class Person{

    private List currentList = null;

    public void addToList(List newList){

        if (newList == null  || newList == currentList) {
            return;
        }

        if (currentList != null){
            currentList.remove(this);
        }

        currentList = newList;
        newList.add(this);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Set

```
static HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
public static void add(ArrayList<String> array, String s)
{
    if(!set.contains(s))
    {
        array.add(s);
    }
}
```

Set can only have unique elements and contains() is O(1), so you don't need to worry about run time. If you are wondering how you can check rather than adding, you can just loop through one array and add all elements it to the set. Then you can loop through the second array and see if the Set contains the elements. If it does, meaning returns true then you have a repeat

Hope this helps!